# How to make bat file functionality in to python exe file

Tags: batch-file, exe

Currently i am creating ".bat" file for Rendering my scene.my "render.bat" has below code.Its working fine.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Autodesk\Maya2012\bin\Render.exe" -r mr "E:\Temp\sp.ma"

I am planing to create ".exe" file with above code Using python.If i click ".exe" it should render my scene same like ".bat" file.How to do this in Python?

Thanks. 
Ram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to have a python script that will execute this .bat file.

Sample code:

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen("batchfile.bat", cwd=r"c:\directory\containing\batchfile")
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()# Returns '0' on success
```

Then you can create an .exe file of this pyhton script file using any one of the following options:

[py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) works on Windows.
[PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) works on Windows and Linux.
[Py2app](http://pythonhosted.org/py2app/) works on the Mac.

I hope it was helpful.